# Count of/ sum of Power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have measure

count(Books[Bookstext]) / sum(Pages[Number of pages])

Do you have any better idea for this measure ?

It is working but not for all slicers buttons which have impact on my line chart. For 2 buttons that measure its ok but for another 2 i see infinity values on my line chart.

Answer (score 0):

I already have a solution. The problem was caused by infinity values.

A better option is to add

```
iferror(count(Books[Bookstext]) / sum(Pages[Number of pages], blank())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the DIVIDE function.

```
DIVIDE (
    COUNT ( Books[Bookstext] ),
    SUM ( Pages[Number of pages] ),
    BLANK ()
)
```